# How to benchmark the startup of my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, initialization, benchmarking

I put my Rails application on Heroku, and I see now that it has a very slow startup time. What I mean by this is that, when I first go to my website on Heroku (with a browser), it takes too much time to display the index page, but when I browse the website afterwards, the requests take normal time.

So how do I see what takes so much time on this "first" request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is normal, because you are not paying for your dyno and the first dyno will be idle out after a certain amount of time.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

> Apps that have only 1 web dyno will be idled out after a period of inactivity. The web dyno will be shut down. When a request comes in to an idled app your web dyno will be automatically spun back up, causing a few second delay for this first request. Subsequent requests will perform normally.
>
> Apps that have more than 1 web dyno are never idled out. Workers dynos are never idled out.

If you want to see what is going on, you can use the command (from you installation directory)

> heroku logs

It will show the logs of your server.

In my staging enviroment, if I query now (when my dyno is idling) I can see in the logs

```
2012-02-18T12:17:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2012-02-18T12:17:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
2012-02-18T12:17:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting

[.....]
2012-02-18T12:17:42+00:00 heroku[router]: GET [...] dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=0
```

=> it took about 20 second to fullfill my first request.